# Razor pay not working in react-native version 0.61.5. Android app crash on razorpayCheckout.open. Any solutions?

Tags: android, react-native, razorpay

All parameters are holding proper values, but app crashes without logs `RazorpayCheckout.open` line.

```
 let options = {
           description: title,
           image: 'https://cdn.razorpay.com/logos/DjijAUZBHCGlv4_medium.png',
           currency: currency,
           key: orderInfo.key,
           amount: base_price,
           name: 'dfgdfg',
           order_id:orderInfo.order_id,
           prefill: {
             email: user.email,
             contact: user.country_code + user.mobile_number,
             name: user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name
           },
            theme: { color: '#F37254' }
   }
     RazorpayCheckout.open(options).then((err,data) => {
         console.log(err,data)
      }).catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
     });
```

Comment: I think order_id:orderInfo.order_id should not be passed. Because order will be created after the payment.

I am also working on Razor pay. I am getting the problems in getting Razor Pay Order Id and Order Id in Transactions history.